# Error with telegrambot in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, telegram, telegram-bot

I have written a telegram bot with webapi in asp.net and it receives updates but in the response the bot sends me this error:

error:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at WebApiNew.Controllers.WebhookController.Post(Update update)

and my code:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public string Post(Update update)
   {
       if (update != null)
       {
           try
           {
               var chatid = update.Message.Chat.Id;
               var text = update.Message.Text;
               bot.SendTextMessage(chatId: chatid, text: text);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               bot.SendTextMessage(chatId: 158272989, text: "error :" + ex.ToString());
           }
       }
       else {
           bot.SendTextMessage(chatId: 158272989, text: "error ");
       }
       return "";
   }
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Updates come as a `collection` of Update objects

Maybe modify your code so post handles an array of updates

Comment: I told you that i have no error Is it possible that the problem is because of telegram.bot component??